# Applying Ford-Fulkerson to settle a business lunch

Tags: algorithms, optimization, network-flow, modelling, ford-fulkerson

I want to organize a business lunch with two societies $E_1$ (mine) and $E_2$. Each society is made of four people from the Executive management and 6 of the Financial Management. I want to organize this lunch with two tables of ten people with the following constraints :

- At least one member of each four department has to be on each table
- At most three people of each department can sit together at a table
- At least three people of each Executive management department have to be at the table $1$.

I did the following graph :

[image]

And applied Ford-Fulkerson (I'm not sure on how to apply it, the itreation are in parenthesis $(number \ of \ the \ iteration)$ ):

[image]

The thing is that I'm not able to let everybody sit ... I have only 8 people from society 2. Do I have too much constraints or did I did a mistake ?

What would be the minimum cut ? Is there a minimum cut if I don't have a maximal stream ? Would it verify the Ford-Fulkerson theorem ?

Comment: Do you *know* that everybody can be seated? What's the *idea* behind your construction?

Comment: @Raphael No I'm not sure ! But as far as I have two tables of ten places for twenty people, everybody can be seated. The thing is that I don't know if I can apply the constraints given by my boss. The *idea* was to find it thanks to my computer science knowledge. The *issue* is that I don't know if I used and applied them (the Ford-Flukerson algorithm) well ! The *purpose* is to have a better understanding of those concepts.

Comment: Okay, so the algorithm finding seats for only 18 people *may* be the correct answer!